# vuejs does not update html when I change data in created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is the link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqKrzY

html looks like

```
<span>items[selected].text: {{ items[selected].text }}</span>
```

and `created`:

```
created() {
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.items[0] = {
        text: "XX"
     };
     this.items[1] = {
        text: "YY"
     };
  }, 1000)
 }
```

this does not update automatically, if I click the select, it will change though.
And if I remove `setTimeout`, it will update automatically.

Comment: try This: `        this.items[0].text = 'XX';
         this.items[1].text = 'YY';`

Comment: It is working fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate array in this way with vue please refer to: [Common Gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

Here is an example how it would work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NezvYV

```
this.items.$set(0, {
            text: "XX"
         })
```

Comment: Well you can read it all in the docs(https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). $set is an alias for Vue.set

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   this.items[0].text = 'XX';
   this.items[1].text = 'YY';
```